# Page Refresh on jquery dialog close

Tags: asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, partial-page-refresh, page-refresh

I want to Refresh aspx page after closing a jquery modal dialog on clicking a button inside jquery modal popup.
my page has update panels in it so consider it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add thisto your jQuery dialog;

```
close: function(ev, ui) { window.location.reload() }
```

Comment: hi Çağdaş Olgun,i will try this and let you know thanks for the quick reply